# Почему пример из документации, для модуля multiprocessing не работает в репл?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Открываю документацию по [модулю](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html), копирую второй пример в IDE:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def f(name):
    print('hello', name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

И получаю вот такой результат:

```
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 115, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'f' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

Тоже самое происходит и в стандартной IDLE, подскажите в чем может быть проблема?

*нашел частичное решение, если вместо multiprocessing использовать multiprocessing.dummy, то кое-что работает, однако все-равно не ясно из за чего это происходит*

Comment: попробуйте в файл с именем `mp_example.py` сохранить код перед запуском. multiprocessing при использовании start method `'spawn'` (по умолчанию на Windows) запускает отдельные процессы и пытается импортировать модуль, а `__name__ == '__main__'` специальное имя (поэтому `mp_example.py`,  а не `__main__.py` файл назвать можно)

Comment: Как ни странно помогло сохраниение и импортирование. Т.е. в одном модуле  if __name__ == '__main__': и вызов - а в другом, вызываемая процессом функция...

Comment: пробовали ли вы вариант, предложенный в первом комментарии? (скопировать код из вопроса в файл mp_example.py. Запустить `python mp_example.py` и никаких других изменений или вторых файлов)

Comment: @jfs, да, проверил, так тоже работает, но это не совсем удобно в плане работы с кодом. Спасибо за наводку.

Comment: если у вас есть какие-то особые требования, которые препятствуют сохранению Питон-кода в файл, то нажмите [edit] и явно их в вопросе упомяните или вообще новый вопрос задайте.

Comment: @jfs, Да нет, таких требований нет, просто удобнее в процессе написания пользоваться реплом чем, каждое действие проверять через сохранение и запуск файла... могу уточнить в вопросе, что не работает именно в репл...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Модуль со скриптом (который процессы создаёт) обязан безопасно импортироваться *без* запуска новых процессов при использовании `spawn` (по умолчанию на Windows), `forkserver` методов запуска. См. пример в документации: [Safe importing of main module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods).

Обычно, достаточно `if __name__ == '__main__'` защиту использовать для частей, которые новые процессы создают. В интерактивном интерпретаторе и в модулях, которые как скрипты выполняются: `__name__ == '__main__'`, поэтому могут ошибки возникать.

Когда вы успешно импортируете `f` из другого модуля, он не будет назван `__main__`, поэтому может не возникнуть ошибка (успешный pickle). Подробнее:

- для запуска нового процесса, вам нужна функция `f`
- чтобы запустить функцию `f`, Питон должен импортировать модуль её содержащий. В новом процессе у вас ничего нет, кроме встроенных имён. Всё остальное явно импортируется
- если модуль назван `__main__` (скрипт или интерактивный случай), то при импорте `if __name__ == '__main__'` выполняется и вы пытаетесь рекурсивно ещё новые процессы запустить (fork bomb). В реализации multiprocessing могут некоторые ухищрения присутствовать, чтобы вместо fork bomb исключение возникло (лучше)
- если модуль не назван `__main__`, то нет проблем с его импортом. В зависимости от особенностей реализации multiprocessing, текущего окружения, может быть достаточно, если `f` является pickable (глобальная функция из модуля, который можно импортировать, попадает в эту категорию)

`multiprocessing.dummy` может работать так как в этом случае создаются новые потоки, а не процессы (все данные общие: глобальная переменная `f`  во всех потоках доступна).

Comment: Возможно я просто чего-то недопонял, но если в интеркакивном интерпретаторе и в модулях, которые выполняются как скрипты `__name__ == '__main__'` то в чем причина ошибки?

Comment: @Amunrah: расширил объяснение

Comment: спасибо, отмечу решением )

Answer (score 2):

Для понимания, может вот такой пример поможет:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import sleep

class A:
    def __call__(self, count=10, sleep_time=0.5):
        for i in range(count):
            print('Working class A, i=%s' % i)
            sleep(sleep_time)


class B:
    def __call__(self, count=10, sleep_time=0.5):
        for i in range(count):
            print('Working class B, i=%s' % i)
            sleep(sleep_time)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A()
    b = B()

    p1 = Process(target=a, kwargs={'sleep_time': 0.7})
    p2 = Process(target=b, args=(12,))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

Comment: Да, пример очень хороший, но у меня он падает с тойже ошибкой...

Comment: странно, я запустил, работает

Comment: Действительно странно, примеры из модуля threading запускаются, проблемма возникает только с процессами... на днях обновил интерпретатор... попробую откатиться

Comment: у меня Python 3.6.3

Comment: @Bormotov Вобщем заработало, только вместо модуля multiprocessing  использовал multiprocessing.dummy из тойже либы...

Comment: @Amunrah отлично :)

Comment: Хочу заметить, что multiprocessing.dummy на самом деле не порождает мультипроцессорность. https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy Иными словами, он порождает лишь потоки. Это не всегда то, что надо. Он может сэкономить время на расспаралеливании ввода-вывода, но не сэкономит время в общем случае.  Кстати, пример из документации, как и исходный пример от @Phil,  с настоящим  multiprocessing у меня тоже не заработали.

Comment: чтобы ошибку воспроизвести, попробуйте `multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')` и в REPL код из вопроса запустите

Comment: @jfs, Попробовал, не помогло...

Comment: @passant заработало. Через импорт, не знаю почему, но все работает

Comment: @Amunrah: что значит "не помогло"? "чтобы ошибку воспроизвести" означает, чтобы получить `AttributeError`. У меня (Ubuntu) без `.set_start_method('spawn')` ваш код в вопросе как есть работает (нет ошибки), а могу получить ошибку AttributeError (воспроизвести ошибку), вызвав `.set_start_method('spawn')`.

Answer (score 2):

Как ни странно, работает, если разнести пример в два модуля:

**example1.py**

```
def f(name):
    print('hello', name)
```

**example2.py**

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from example1 import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Внес изменения, спасибо за уточнение в коментах.

Comment: Странно. Во-первых, у меня работает только если фразу "from multiprocessing import Process" перенести в файл example2.py, а во-вторых, что еще более странно - запускается и работает в MS Visual Studio и по-прежнему не работает в Spyder

Comment: @passant, Возможно, у меня заработало так, поэтому не проверял, но так впринципе логичнее конечно. По поводу других странностей нашел вот такой ответ: https://bugs.python.org/issue25053 возможно он поможет прояснить ситуацию, пока не было времени углубляться.